# Transform a working Java aplication to mobile

Tags: java, android

I developed a small java application (jar file), nothing fancy except to take some text in some text boxes and some dropdown menus, that translate some other string sequences that is needed for my job.
Works great on the pc. 
I never did something similar on a mobile and I wonder if there is a simple way to transforme threw the Netbeans IDE to run on an adroid application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That would be awesome if there was software that would take any arbitrary JAR and turn it into an app for you.

Comment: Because the swing part needs to be rewritten/transformed, do a prototype transformation, and first refactor the sources to have an easy migration to Android, first tested with swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you have developed desktop application probably with Swing or AWT. Both are not directly supported by Android that introduces its own API that allows to develop application that lives in Android context. You obviously cannot translate Swing to Android automatically.

If your application is designed well (e.g. uses MVC pattern) you can reuse Model and Controller and re-write the View only. If however your application is very simple and does not have well defined layers you probably have to re-write it from scratch  for Android.